# Detox cannot find adb if run via GithubActions

Tags: adb, github-actions, detox

I got an error during the attempt to run android tests on mac OS machine via github actions

```
DetoxRuntimeError: Detox instance has not been initialized
    HINT: There was an error on attempt to call detox.init()
    Error: There was no "adb" executable file in directory: ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools.
    Check integrity of your Android SDK.
```

Actually, the issues is reproduced only when I run tests in CI through github actions, but when I connect to this machine via SSH - all works fine. Looks like it depends on used shell?

Also even if I execute the command `adb` via  GithubActions - it works!
I can’t understand what is wrong…

Comment: Could you share the workflow `.yml` file to check how you implemented it please?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk
```

before npm script execution.

Comment: where did you add that?

Comment: use if you need. it helps